# failing to ssh into ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I was following these [ec2 setup instructions](http://rsms.me/2011/03/23/ec2-wep-app-template.html) and when I get to the end where I need to use

```
ssh -i path/to/myapp.pem ubuntu@XXX.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I get the following error

```
$ ssh -i ~/keys/scriptishsitekey.pem ec2-blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com
The authenticity of host 'ec2-blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com (1.2.3.4)' can't     be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ..
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes 
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com,1.2.3.4' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

where I've hidden some of the details there, but the info I used should be correct, any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `ec2-user` instead of `ubuntu`.

Your command would then be:

```
ssh -i path/to/myapp.pem ec2-user@XXX.compute.amazonaws.com
```